# UpdatePanelAnimation helper in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to create a helper function for UpdatePanelAnimation extender from AjaxControlToolkit in asp.net mvc. I downloaded the toolkit and loaded the js files into my project.

Can someone please tell me how should I write this helper function and what all parameters are to be passed into it.

I am new to asp.net and mvc

---

thanks for the reply. but we have to include more helper functions in mvc in the near future. so i need to implement this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have jQuery, using UpdatePanel and UpdatePanelAnimation is not desired in ASP.NET MVC. You can use jQuery Animate method:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/#source

First you call `animate` to hide panel, then you use `post` or `get` ajax method and in callback you call `animate` to come back to previous state. If you do it properly, it will look like UpdatePanelAnimation and have very nice looking code.